# how can I refactor a container to use a predicate method directly?

Tags: c++, templates, functional-programming, refactoring, c++11

The snippet below works.  However, it's a bit ugly because it uses a static method to wrap a method call to a predicate.

In other words, I would like to replace:

```
c.remove_if_true( Value::IsOdd );   // static method
```

with something like

```
c.remove_if_true( Value::isOdd );   // member method
```

There should be one fewer level of indirection and hopefully, the resultant code would be clearer.

**How do I refactor my code to call `isOdd()` directly without having to go through a static method wrapper?**

However, if this implementation is as clear as I can make this code, also let me know.  TIA.

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

template< typename T >
class MyContainer
{
public:
    typedef std::function<bool(const T& t)>   PREDICATE;

public:
    void remove_if_true( PREDICATE predicate )
    {
        // NOTE: use implementation from KennyTM's answer below
    }
private:
    std::vector< T >  m_vec;
};

class Value
{
public:
    Value( int i ) : m_i( i ) { }
    bool isOdd() const { return m_i%2==1; }
    static bool IsOdd( const Value& v ) { return v.isOdd(); }
private:
    int m_i;
};


int main()
{
    MyContainer<Value> c;

    c.remove_if_true( Value::IsOdd );  // would like to replace with Value::isOdd here
}
```

### Solution using KennyTM's Answer

**ataylor's suggestion `std::mem_fun_ref()` required with gcc 4.6.1 and other compilers not completely up-to-date with latest standards**

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

template< typename T >
class MyContainer
{
public:
    typedef std::const_mem_fun_ref_t<bool, T>  PREDICATE;

public:
    void remove_if( PREDICATE predicate )
    {
        auto old_end = m_vec.end();
        auto new_end = std::remove_if(m_vec.begin(), old_end, predicate);
        m_vec.erase(new_end, old_end);
    }
private:
    std::vector< T >  m_vec;
};

class Value
{
public:
    Value( int i ) : m_i( i ) { }
    bool isOdd() const { return m_i%2==1; }
private:
    int m_i;
};


int main()
{
    MyContainer<Value> c;

    c.remove_if( std::mem_fun_ref( &Value::isOdd ));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
c.remove_if_true( std::mem_fn(&Value::isOdd) );
```

---

BTW, is there any reason you need to avoid `std::remove_if`?

```
void remove_if_true(PREDICATE predicate)
{
    auto old_end = m_vec.end();
    auto new_end = std::remove_if(m_vec.begin(), old_end, predicate);
    m_vec.erase(new_end, old_end);
}
```

Comment: +1 excellent point about remove_if() - it replaces my entire internal implementation for remove_if_true...  ...but what does the typedef for my PREDICATE become with your answer?

Comment: Regarding the first part: The definition of PREDICATE uses a reference instead of a pointer, so `std::mem_fn_ref` is needed instead of `std::mem_fn`

Comment: +1 @ataylor - tyvm - that's the very last part that I couldn't figure out

Comment: @ataylor: No it works for const references. See C++11 §20.8.2[func.require]/1 yourself. `std::mem_fun_ref` (§D.8.2.2[depr.member.pointer.adaptors]/7) has been deprecated, and all use cases can be supported by `std::bind` or `std::mem_fn`.

Comment: @KennyTM I stand corrected.  However, my compiler does require `std::mem_fun_ref` at the moment

Answer (score 3):

`c.remove_if_true( std::bind( &Value::isOdd, _1 ) );`

Comment: The _1 is a placeholder for the Value instance.

Comment: But where does the instance come from? I can only get this to work: std::bind(&Value::isOdd, Value(), _1);

Comment: @juanchopanza: Try to add `using std::placeholders::_1;` somewhere.

Comment: @KennyTM Yes, I got that. As I said, std::bind(&Value::isOdd, Value(), _1) works for me, std::bind(&Value::isOdd, _1) does not. My understanding is that it shouldn't work.

Comment: @KennyTM, sorry, brain fart on my side. I failed to see that the class originating the predicate is the same as the one the predicate is applied to. +1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::mem_fn_ref` to wrap `isOdd`:

```
c.remove_if_true( std::mem_fun_ref(&Value::isOdd) );
```

Comment: +1 - ty for adding the comment above - I almost missed your answer in the flurry of responses...

Answer (score 1):

Best way use lambdas :

```
c.remove_if_true( [] (const Value & v) { return v.get() % 2 == 0; } );
```

Or more self-commented :

```
auto isOdd = [] (const Value & v) { return v.get() % 2 == 0; };
c.remove_if_true( isOdd );
```

Comment: the lambda would be a good solution if the class has a get() member function and not an isOdd() member function. In that case you don't want to "intrude" on your Value class by having to give it a method for the purpose of the operation you want to do on it, and you don't have to start creating named functions or functors for it.

Comment: @CashCow: You can always call `Value::isOdd` from the lambda: `[](const Value &v) {return v.isOdd();}`. Of course `std::mem_fn` is probably a cleaner solution in this particular case...